# Slugs not appearing in URLS

Tags: django, slug

I want my slugs to show up in my URLS instead of the number ID of the image that is being viewed. I can't seem to get it working. Can anyone spot what I'm missing/doing wrong? TYIA

**models.py:**

```
class PostImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to="images", default="default.png")
    image_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.image_title
    
    class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'PostImage'
```

**views.py:**

```
def galleryPage(request):
    images = PostImage.objects.all()
    context = {'images':images}

    return render(request, 'gallery.html', context)


def viewImage(request, slug):
    photo = PostImage.objects.get(id=slug)
    return render(request, 'viewimage.html', {'photo': photo, 'slug': slug})
```

**urls.py:**

```
path('viewimage/<slug:slug>/', views.viewImage, name='viewimage'),
```

**admin.py:**

```
@admin.register(PostImage)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('image_title',)}
```

These are the html pages, the first is where the image is clicked, the second is where the image is shown and also where I would want the slug showing in the URL on browser rather than the id/number.

**html for page that image is selected:**

```
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>{% include 'navbardesktop.html' %}</header>
    <div class="container-gallery">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="gallerygrid1">
        <div class="row">
          {% for photo in images %}
          <div class="col-md-4" id="gallerygrid2">
            <a href="{% url 'viewimage' photo.id %}"
              ><img
                class="gallery-thumbnail"
                src="{{photo.image.url}}"
                style=""
            /></a>
          </div>
          {% empty %}
          <h3>No Projects...</h3>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**html for page where image is shown:**

```
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>{% include 'navbardesktop.html' %}</header>
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="image-post">
        <a href="{% url 'gallery' %}"
          ><img class="photo-img" src="{{photo.image.url}}"
        /></a>
        <h2 class="photo-title">{{photo.image_title}}</h2>
        <p class="contact">
          Interested in purchasing this as a print? Contact me for more
          information regarding price and sizes.
        </p>
        <a href="{% url 'contact' %}" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"
          >Contact</a
        >
        <a href="{% url 'gallery' %}" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"
          >Gallery</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your urls where?  In your template?  The admin site?

Comment: Sorry... the actual url displayed in the browser, so the link it's self when the image is clicked on the gallery page and opened on a new page. At the moment it's showing a number. I want it to be example.com/viewimage/<slug>

Comment: Can you add the template with the url that opens example.com/viewimage/<slug>.

Comment: I added to the question. @raphael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
The url that is opening the page with the image is `<a href="{% url 'viewimage' photo.id %}">`, and since you are feeding in `photo.id`, that's what you're getting.  You could change it to `<a href="{% url 'viewimage' photo.slug %}">` and that should solve the problem.

**But**
*But* this will create problems since you are allowing `null=True` for the `slug` field, so what happens when you have a `PostImage` instance with no `slug`?  An error, since your url is *expecting* a parameter, `<slug:slug>`:

```py
path('viewimage/<slug:slug>/', views.viewImage, name='viewimage'),
```

I don't see why you need to make the slug field null, since you have a save() function that will fill it in automatically, though it does have a typo, I believe, and that is `slugify(self.title)`.  What is `self.title`?  Perhaps you meant `self.image_title`?:

```py
class PostImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to="images", default="default.png")
    image_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.image_title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

**Unfortunately**
*Unfortunately*, there is still something that will go wrong in your views, since you are trying to get a `photo = PostImage.objects.get(slug=slug)`, but now `slug` will be an actual slug, not an id.  Easy to fix:

```py
def viewImage(request, slug):
    photo = PostImage.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'viewimage.html', {'photo': photo, 'slug': slug})
```

And since you should never try to get an object without checking if it can be done first:

```py
def viewImage(request, slug):
    try:
        photo = PostImage.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except PostImage.DoesNotExist:
        print("PostImage with this slug does not exist")
        photo = None
    return render(request, 'viewimage.html', {'photo': photo, 'slug': slug})
```

Comment: I know I'm not meant to do this.... but what an amazing answer... very intuitive. Thank you ever so much. I did have to edit your last snipper from (id=slug) to (slug=slug) but that's only thanks to what you've just taught me :)

Comment: Thanks @DavidHenson and glad I was of help!

Comment: Im sorry to ask another question, but when trying this on live server, its asking me to add a default value... what should this be? As you said adding null=True breaks it so I cant add this.

Comment: You can add anything like `'xxxxxx'` just keep in mind that any `PostImage` instance with no value of `slug` will have this value until you change it.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is my pre-existing images that I've already uploaded won't work when adding a slug, I fixed by re uploading them all manually again,  but I also have alot of blog posts I want to do this for and would much prefer not to re do all the blog posts?

Comment: Not sure, but can you add your blog post models.  I mean the only database change made was making a previous column that could be null, not null.